# Fixing the size of the header in Beamer

Tags: beamer, header-footer, height

I found a template that I like but the header is not fixed and it increases as function of the number of sections present in the document. It is a template ready from Radboud University Nijmegen.

[image]

I would like to remove the 5 text lines (Introduction, Background infomration, ...) and leave black (empty). The problem is that if I do so the height of the header gets reduced. Is it possible to fix it at a specific height?

The related part of the code I think is this:

```
\defbeamertemplate*{headline}{ru theme}{%
  \leavevmode%
  \@tempdimb=2.4375ex%
    \multiply\@tempdimb by\beamer@sectionmax%
  \pgfdeclareimage[height=.9\@tempdimb]{logo}{ru_logo}%
  \logo{\pgfuseimage{logo}}%
  \ifdim\@tempdimb>0pt%
    \advance\@tempdimb by 1.125ex%
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.5\paperwidth,ht=\@tempdimb]{section in head/foot}%
      \vbox to\@tempdimb{\vfil\insertsectionnavigation{.5\paperwidth}\vfil}%
    \end{beamercolorbox}%
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.4\paperwidth,ht=\@tempdimb,right]{subsection in head/foot}%
      \vbox to\@tempdimb{\vfil\vfil\textbf{\footnotesize\insertshortinstitute~~}\vfil}%
    \end{beamercolorbox}%
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.1\paperwidth,ht=\@tempdimb,left]{subsection in head/foot}%
      \vbox to\@tempdimb{\vfil\insertlogo\vfil\vfil}%
    \end{beamercolorbox}%
  \fi%
}
```

Thank you in advance for any your helpful tip!

Comment: Try this: comment out three `\vbox`s inside `beamercolorbox` environment.

Comment: Why you do not want sections creating pdf bookmarks?

Comment: I works ... partially. 
If I remove all the three `\vbox` lines it disappears also the text on the right cell with the university logo. If I remove only the first one it works but I have to keep the sections otherwise the heading disappears completely and if I keep the sections i find them on the booktabs.

The first one is related to the black index
The second one is related to the university name
The third one is related to the university logo

I can do specifying a generic section and setting the starting header value:`\@tempdimb=2.4375ex%`

Nice would be to avoid having sections

Comment: Because I have a special document of three pages, similar to a flyer and I would like to make this with beamer

Comment: You can also change `\@tempdimb=2.4375ex%` to the total height, remove `\multiply\@tempdimb by\beamer@sectionmax%` and `\vbox to\@tempdimb{\vfil\insertsectionnavigation{.5\paperwidth}\vfil}%`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like

```
\defbeamertemplate*{headline}{ru theme}{%
  \leavevmode%
  % set a minimum number of sections, here 5 is used
  \ifnum\beamer@sectionmax<5\relax
    \beamer@sectionmax=5
  \fi
  \@tempdimb=2.4375ex%
    \multiply\@tempdimb by\beamer@sectionmax%
  \pgfdeclareimage[height=.9\@tempdimb]{logo}{ru_logo}%
  \logo{\pgfuseimage{logo}}%
  \ifdim\@tempdimb>0pt%
    \advance\@tempdimb by 1.125ex%
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.5\paperwidth,ht=\@tempdimb]{section in head/foot}%
      % \vbox to\@tempdimb{\vfil\insertsectionnavigation{.5\paperwidth}\vfil}%
    \end{beamercolorbox}%
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.4\paperwidth,ht=\@tempdimb,right]{subsection in head/foot}%
      \vbox to\@tempdimb{\vfil\vfil\textbf{\footnotesize\insertshortinstitute~~}\vfil}%
    \end{beamercolorbox}%
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.1\paperwidth,ht=\@tempdimb,left]{subsection in head/foot}%
      \vbox to\@tempdimb{\vfil\insertlogo\vfil\vfil}%
    \end{beamercolorbox}%
  \fi%
}
```

Comment: It works very well. Thankyou very much. At the end you added `\ifnum\beamer@sectionmax<5\relax
    \beamer@sectionmax=5` which set a minimum of sections to 5 even if you have zero sections and accordingly to this it creates the right size box.